# Php doesn't show errors sometimes and other times it shows

Tags: php

I have this:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
dsadafsaf();
```

This show error in normal way like this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function dsadafsaf()
```

But this:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
dsadafsaf
//without () to ask for a function, should give me parse error right?
```

Instead of show the error, gives me **HTTP ERROR 500**

I'm using php 7.4 as php-fpm

I tried to use only E_ALL instead of E_ALL | E_STRICT

Comment: What web server? Have you checked the error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the parse error is being triggered and stopping the file from being compiled. Because it is not compiled, PHP doesn't know to set `display_errors = On`.

You need to modify the php.ini file and set the value there.

Comment: Then when we have a parse error, 0 lines works, even if we have something like 1000 lines before the parse error? I'll test it now!

Comment: Yes, this is the error. I'll never think on that if have no comments ^^. So, thank you so much!